# query sqlite database has outofboundException

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an `ArrayList` which I try to convert to String[] so I can query my database but I get `outofboundException` and I don't know where is the problem?

to convert arraylist to string[] :

```
String[] idsArray = new String[selectedTopicIds.size()];
    idsArray = selectedTopicIds.toArray(idsArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedTopicIds.size(); i++) {
        idsArray[i] = selectedTopicIds.get(i);
    }
```

then I use Cursor to query:

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.query(Util.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            Util.KEY_TOPIC + "=?",
            idsArray,
            null,
            null,
            null);
```

and this is how cursor loops:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Word word = new Word();
            word.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
          
            wordList.add(word);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
```

and on the line that I give it `idsArray` I have this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 35
> because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.

both arraylist and String[] must have 35 elements from index 0 to 34

I don't understand where is the problem?

Comment: it means that index 35 in your array doesn't exist. Ergo you don't have enough items in your array and you are calling something that doesn't exist.

Comment: [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace (see logcat) `The statement has 1 parameters.` means that your query statement contains only one `?` character.

Comment: I know but how can I make my cursor to don't call index 35?

Comment: I've added the cursor looping function

Comment: index 35 means its asking for a 36th element

Comment: Your selection `Util.KEY_TOPIC + "=?"` contains only 1 `?` placeholder. Why do you pass the array `idsArray` which may contain more than 1 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to match the column `Util.KEY_TOPIC` against the items of the array `idsArray`?
If so, you should not use the operator `=` but the operator `IN` and construct the `selection` argument of the method `query()` so that is contains as many `?` placeholders as the number of items of `idsArray`.

An easier way to do this is to create a comma separated list of all the items of `idsArray`, something like `",1,2,3"` with `Arrays.toString()`:

```
String ids = Arrays.toString(idsArray).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ",").replace(" ", "");
```

and use the operator `LIKE`:

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.query(
    Util.TABLE_NAME,
    null,
    "? LIKE '%,' || " + Util.KEY_TOPIC + " || ',%'",
    new String[] {ids},
    null,
    null,
    null
);
```